# SlideToggle does not work in my MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

My code used to work, now it does not. Nothing happens when I click a paragraph. I know it enters the script.

This is my script:

```
<script>
    function showhide(element_id) {
        $(element_id).slideToggle();
    };
</script>
```

Edit: This is my rendered markup . It creates divs that should expand/collapse when I click the paragraph:

```
<div class="tab-content">

    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">            

            <div class="relation-link">
                <p class="expand-one" onclick="showhide('dep-rtgdep-rtg')" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">dep-rtg</p>
                <table id=dep-rtgdep-rtg class="content-one" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fr&#229;n sektion:</td>
                        <td class="rightcell">dep-rtg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Till sektion:</td>
                        <td class="rightcell">dep-rtg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bara till samma programkod:</td>
                        <td class="rightcell">True</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>             
            }
```

I don´t paste the css, since it has not been changed since it worked.
Help would be much appreciated

Comment: What js error do you get?

Comment: please post the rendered markup, as the razor syntax is quite hard to debug

Comment: No error. It just does not expand the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :-

```
<script>
    function showhide(element_id) {
        $('#' + element_id).slideToggle(); // use '#' id selector
    };
</script>
```